# "in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::max<int, int>' requested here" Error Message for max() function

Tags: c++, max

While trying to solve http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=891, I coded :

```
vector<int> abc(3) ;
vector<int> counter(3) ;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    abc[i] = i ;
}

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int a,b,g ;
    ifstr >> a >> b >> g ;
    a-- ;
    b-- ;
    g-- ;

    swap(abc[a], abc[b]) ;
    counter[abc[g]]++ ;
}
ofstr << std::max(counter[0], counter[1], counter[2]) ;
return 0 ;
```

I got +4 overloads on my max() function. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that `std::max` was defined for more than 2 arguments

Comment: `std::max` does **not** have an overload that accepts 3 values (unless they are in an initializer list). See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max.

Comment: std::max_element will work on your vector

Comment: Documentation for [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: @MarcusMüller The only overload with more than two arguments is one where the third argument is a custom comparator.

Comment: Your entire error message said more than you are sharing here.  Did you read it all?  Do you agree with it?  I suspect it detailed exactly why your call to `std::max` was malformed.

Comment: Gregarious, any progress? Did any of the answers help? Please ask if you want anything clarified.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to use [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) with anything else than 2 arguments is by using an initializer list:

```
ofstr << std::max( { counter[0], counter[1], counter[2] } );
//                 ^                                    ^
```

Alternatively, you could use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) which doesn't require a copy of all the elements like the initializer list does. Instead you give it the `begin` and `end` iterators of your container:

```
ofstr << *std::max_element(std::begin(counter), std::end(counter));
//       ^
```

Note that it returns an *iterator* to the found element (or the `end` iterator) and it needs to be dereferenced to get the actual value, hence the `*` above.

Answer (score 3):

Given your counter, you can do this

```
ofstr << *std::max_element(counter.begin(), counter.end());
```

(if you include the algorithm header).